# Vertical & horizontal flow with line height on <small> tag

Tags: html, tags, vertical-alignment, css

I'm sorting out my typography for a new website and have a strange occurrence with the `<small>` tag - it's throwing my line-height out. Everything else is fine (heading tags, paragraph etc) but the `small` is throwing it out somewhere.

Here's an image of what I mean:

[image]

My question is where is this extra little bit of `line-height` coming from and how can I correct it?

There's a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nq2dt/ and code below.

I'm using `rem` units so this won't be compatible with IE8 and below for now. I'm on Firefox 19.0.

HTML

```
<div>
    <h1>Main Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p><small>Small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here small text goes here.</small></p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div>
    <h2>Sub heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <h3>Sub heading</h3>
    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html { font-size: 100%; }

body { font-size: 1rem; line-height: 1.75rem; font-family: open sans; text-align: justify; margin: 0; }

h1 { font-size: 2.625rem; margin: 0 0 1.75rem; }
h2 { font-size: 1.625rem; margin: 0 0 1.75rem; }
h3 { font-size: 1.25rem; margin: 0 0 1.75rem; }
p { font-size: 1rem; margin: 0 0 1.75rem; line-height: 1.75rem; }
small { font-size: 0.8125rem; }

div { width: 48%; margin: 0 1%; float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the line-height to a decimal without a unit seems to fix the problem:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y96b/)

```
small { font-size: 0.8125rem; line-height: 1.75; }
```

Setting `display:block` also seems to fix the issue, but this is not really a desirable fix obviously.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g22Vv/)

```
small { font-size: 0.8125rem; display:block; }
```

Comment: Good idea, I though the very same! However small is an inline element for good reason and I'd like to keep it that way if at all possible. I know I could probably use a span in there instead but, you know, semantic markup and all that...

Comment: Alternatively, an explicit `line-height` value could be specified for the `small` element.

Comment: The `1.75` has done it. Funny that cos I tried `1.75rem` and the problem persisted. What's the difference?!!

Comment: My comment on explicit `line-height` wasn't right. Setting this attribute for an inline element has no effect. See this, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742525/is-there-a-way-to-set-min-line-height-on-inline-element-in-css