# about span and div, can not vertical?

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

picture 1 span and div can not center vertical.
if I add text to div，span and div is center vertical.
like picture 2.why?

[image]

```css
.bc {
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    width:400px;
}
.tips {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;

}
```

```html
<span class="tips">SO</span><div class="bc"></div>
```

Comment: share your code here ( create a working snippet ) and also please be more specific about the problem

Comment: ok.next time i will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to vertical align the span to top. As i see it's 'pretty hard' to share some code, i copied the code from the images you shared, and also edited you question with it

```css
.bc {
 background-color:red;
 display:inline-block;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 width:400px;
}
.tips {
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<span class="tips">SO</span><div class="bc"></div>
```

Comment: I want to know what caused it.if not add "vertical-align:top"

Comment: @dykily span is an `inline` element, it doesn't take in consideration `line-height` or `height` . see here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742525/is-there-a-way-to-set-min-line-height-on-inline-element-in-css . Inline elements are tricky business. The fix for your specific problem, is to align the span to the top . Read more about inline elements and their heights, here on SO for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bc {
 background-color:red;
 display:inline-block;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 width:400px;
  float:right;
}
.tips {

 float:left;
}
```

```html
<span class="tips">SO</span><div class="bc"></div>
```

Comment: you don't understand my mean.i want to know，when add text to div，span and div is center vertical.

Comment: Hi, please consider adding explanations to your answers, rather than just blocks of code, to make them more helpful. I recommend you look around at other highly voted/ accepted answers.